# Laplace transform of $te^{-2t}\sin(2t)u(t-3)$

Tags: laplace-transform

**Laplace transform of  $te^{-2t}\sin(2t)u(t-3)$**

I do know the following *properties of Laplace Transform*:

**A)** $t f(t) = \frac {dF(S)}{ds}$

**B)** $e^{at} f(t) = F(S+a)$

But from what I see a part of  the function is in terms of $t$: $te^{-2t}\sin(2t)$ and the other in terms of $t-3$: $u(t-3)$

**So how do I approach this?**

Also this is the waveform of $u(t-3)$

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Hint**: Take $f(t)=t\sin(2t)$, and rewrite it as $\Im(te^{i2t})$, find $\Im(\mathscr{L}\{f(t)\})$ by applying $s$-shifting once. To the result of this, apply $s$-shifting again with $\mathscr{L}\{e^{-4t}f(t)\}$. On getting this, multiply the result by $e^{-3s}$, which follows from the $t$-shifting theorem.

If you wish to use the definition, you may write the following and apply integration by parts to arrive at the answer.

$$\mathscr{L}\{te^{-4t}\sin(2t)u(t-3)\}=\int_{3}^{\infty}te^{-4t}\sin(2t)dt$$